# Right way to draw flowcharts

Tags: flow-charts

Let's say my mobile app has a 3 intro screens **Screen1, Screen2, Screen3** that are shown at the 1st launch. When Screen1 and Screen2 screens are swiped right the next screen is shown. Also there is a **"skip"** button on them that redirects to the **Main Screen**. On Screen3 screen there is a **"start"** button which also redirects to the **Main screen**. Screen2 and Screen3 can be swiped left to see the previous screen.

I need to draw a flowchart of it. Which way us more canonical? Certainly the 2nd way is more compact but do you consider it ok?

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

Comment: Why you want this flow chart for ?

Comment: Flow chart 2 looks.more eligant , how is this related to testing . I didn't downvote

Comment: It would be used to write test cases. Also it would be used to document the normal behavior of the app - what the analysts had to do.

Comment: @PDHide do you think than this question should be moved to stack?

Comment: unless you explain more about what was your confusion its hard to answer than yes or no, i have added what we use in testing

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about project management unrelated to testing are off-topic here, but can be asked on Project Management Exchange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any documentation or process is to make the communication more easier and visually understandable.

So what flowchart to use or what documentation to use will solely depend on the audience/organization to which this is indented to.

So first flowchart doesn't give any clear communication to user , it looks too much complex. Second one looks easier to understand:

In test we usually use state transfer/Transition diagram than flow chart ,

**Diagram:**

[image]

**State Transition Table:**

Here left most column shows the current state of the system , and header shows the actions and the value in the corresponding column shows the new state after the action is performed.

[image]

Comment: The first two paragraphs are a lesson everyone should keep in mind. Congrats for pointing out PDHide.

Comment: @joas Thanks Joao , I have seen people trying to keep some international standards and make some documentation so complex forgetting the fact that those standards where to make things more easier and comprehensive to understand and are just recommendations . In agile world such complex documentations doesn't have much role